# Difference between pojo vs model class in java

Tags: java, model, pojo

I am working on android app in which I am using `gson` library for serialization & de(serialization).

Below is the java class I am using for serialization & de(serialization). I am not sure is this model or pojo class.

```
public class Result {
    private String userId;
    private String sessionId;
}
```

Can anyone share what it is main difference between model & pojo class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This would be a model class.

Model classes often represent a composition of properties from more than one POJO/POCO class for a specific use.

In your case, you have both a User and Session class. Your Result class is a composite of properties from your Session and User classes.

Comment: How this is model ? what should be in this so that it would be POJO